# the number of vowels in a file

Tags: apache-pig

Can someone help me with this? Thanks very much. And this is my code:

```
G = LOAD 'input.txt' AS (line:chararray);
B = foreach G generate FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(LOWER(line), '(?<=.)(?=.)')) as s:chararray;
C = foreach B generate FLATTEN(TOBAG(*)) as letter;
result = filter C by ( letter == 'a' or  letter == 'e' or letter == 'i' or letter == 'o' or letter == 'u' );
E = GROUP result BY letter;
F = foreach E generate group, COUNT(result) ;
DUMP F；
```

Comment: what issue are you facing after executing this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First tokenize the line into words and then get the characters from the words.Use replace to slice the characters in the words.Instead of using TOBAG(*),use tokenize to split the characters along the replaced delimiter.Filter aeiou,then group by the character and get the counts.

**PigScript**

```
A = LOAD 'test4.txt' as (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE  FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) as words;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE  FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(REPLACE(LOWER(words),'','|'),'|')) as letter;
D = FILTER C BY (letter == 'a' or  letter == 'e' or letter == 'i' or letter == 'o' or letter == 'u' );
E = group D by letter;
F = FOREACH E GENERATE group as letter,COUNT(D.letter) as total;
DUMP F;
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code to get the results.

`A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(REPLACE(LOWER((chararray)$0),'','|'),'|')) as letter:chararray;
result = FILTER B by (letter == 'a' or  letter == 'e' or letter == 'i' or letter == 'o' or letter == 'u');
E = GROUP result BY letter;
F = FOREACH E GENERATE group, COUNT(result);
DUMP F;`